# How would be the sort for the beolw JS ,if i need to sort by {entry.heat)?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, variables

I tried to retrieve data through a live server and display them through my local web application, the code to fetch the data by the user`s levels.

How I can sort them either by their levels or views `entry.heat`?

The levels or views `entry.heat` are values in the server and both are variables, so kindly check the below code in order to sort by `entry.heat`.

```
   function(r){
        var max = $('#limit').val();
        if (r.data.video_info.length < max) max = r.data.video_info.length;

        for (index = 0; index < max; index++) {
            var entry = r.data.video_info[index];
            
            var level = parseInt(entry.level);
        

        
            
                            if ((level > $('#min').val()) && (level < $('#max').val())) {
                count++;
                var h = '<div class="entry '+(entry.sex==0?'female':'male')+'"><img src="'+entry.smallcover+'">'+'<span>Heat:<span>'+entry.heat+'</span></h3>';

                $('#main').append(h);

            
        }
    }

            
        if ((current_page < 100) && (count < $('#limit').val() )) {
            current_page++;
            setTimeout(function(){
                doSearch();
            },0);
        }

    }


});
```

Comment: please understand that Java and JavaScript are not the same. Tagging a JavaScript question with Java won't get your question answered any faster.

Answer (score 0):

You make it hard to answer your question, since the source code is not formatted correctly. Also you say, you want to sort depending on the value of `entry.heat` but the code snippet doesn't show any reference to heat.

I'll try to answer though:
In order to sort an array in javascript you would like to use `your_array.sort()`.
`sort(arg: function)` takes a function as argument. In this function you will be presented with two entries of you array. Your function shall tell which of two entries comes first. The function shall return a negative number, if `entryB` comes before `entryA`, a positive number if `entryA` comes before `entryB` or `0` if both entries are equal in case of the sorting property.

I assume in your case it would be:

```
your_array.sort((entryA, entryB) => {
  return etryA.heat - entryB.heat;
});
```

or event shorter:

```
your_array.sort((a, b) => a.heat - b.heat);
```

Read on here: [JavaScript: Array Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)